# Parsing price from loosely structured text

Tags: regex, algorithm

I am writing script that parse prices from classified ads on forum.

Text is very badly structured, sometimes price is present, sometime it isnt. Sometimes users add remark that same item would cost 100 euros in shop, but they sell it for 80 euros. And i want to get price 80 euro from such ad.

In other cases, they sell more different items, each with its own price, and I want to get sum of prices. In other cases, they have special price for those who buy all the things, in this case, I want to get price for whole set, which is usually lower than sum of all prices.

Right now I am doing it with a bunch of regex and some if-s. A am wondering if there are any algorithms, that can do something like this, but I am not aware of them?

Comment: That doesn't sound very "regular" to me.

Answer (score 2):

You are really talking about text analysis that goes way beyond regular expressions, that is just going to help you pull prices out. You're going to have to scan for phrases like 'was x euro, now asking y euro'.

I would recommend you get a large set of real sample input data, the larger the better, with known prices you want to produce. You can then hook up your analyzer and look at records where your analyzer failed and try to figure out why and fix it until you're happy with the results.

The Lucene project has an analysis module normally used for preparing text to be indexed that might be helpful, you can normalize input and write your own custom analyzers to process incoming tokens. I believe it has a tokenizer with built-in regex support, but I can't remember for sure.

Comment: ok, thanks. Will take a look at it, but probably i will just stick with some more regex and ifs :)

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0360__Regular-Expression/Matchingmoneydd2.htm